# Tentando realizar login com o Facebook e retorna FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled

Tags: facebook, objective-c, api

O Login pelo Facebook no iOS funciona de 3 formas:

- Tenta logar pelo login nativo do iOS, caso o usuário possua essa opção configurada;
- Tenta logar pelo aplicativo do Facebook, caso este esteja instalado;
- Abre o site do Facebook no Safari para o usuário logar.

Meu problema acontece somente no primeiro caso. Se o usuário tentar logar utilizando o login nativo do iOS este retorna FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled. Já verifiquei a permissão na área de Privacidade do iOS e está OK. O meu aplicativo já está fora do modo sandbox e o AppID confirma com o App ID no Facebook.

Segue o código de login:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _flag = 0;

    UIBarButtonItem *botaoFechar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fechar" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(fechar)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = botaoFechar;


    delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    [HUD removeFromSuperViewOnHide];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 120, 60)];
    loginView.readPermissions = @[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];
    loginView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

#pragma mark - Facebook
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

    // If the user should perform an action outside of you app to recover,
    // the SDK will provide a message for the user, you just need to surface it.
    // This conveniently handles cases like Facebook password change or unverified Facebook accounts.
    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error]) {
        alertTitle = @"Facebook error";
        alertMessage = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];

        // This code will handle session closures that happen outside of the app
        // You can take a look at our error handling guide to know more about it
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
        alertTitle = @"Session Error";
        alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

        // If the user has cancelled a login, we will do nothing.
        // You can also choose to show the user a message if cancelling login will result in
        // the user not being able to complete a task they had initiated in your app
        // (like accessing FB-stored information or posting to Facebook)
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login %@", error);

        // For simplicity, this sample handles other errors with a generic message
        // You can checkout our error handling guide for more detailed information
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else {
        alertTitle  = @"Something went wrong";
        alertMessage = @"Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
    [HUD show:YES];
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    if(_flag == 0){
        [self loginComUsuario:user];
        _flag++;
    }

}
```

O log retornado é:

```
2014-08-25 14:40:08.065 ShowApp[360:60b] user cancelled login Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x146b2410 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)", com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x146ad8d0, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 600192863435061, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x14562020>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.